# How to work with data on multiple selection within a filter being applied?

Tags: excel, vba

I had to rework the code a bit as I got the *Error1004: pastespecial method of worksheet class failed* I just specified the range for *PasteSpecial xlPasteValues* see the code:

```
Sub AvoidingSelect()

Dim rng As Range, cll As Range Set rng = Range("G2:G12854")

Sheets("Data").Range("G2:G12854").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets("Data").Range("G2:G12854").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

For Each cll In rng

If IsNumeric(cll.Value) Then  Range("G2:G12854") = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(cll.Value, 8) End If

Next End Sub
```

However, the last part is not working. It picks the first cell.value in the row and copy it into each cell all the way down so the value of cell H1084 is in every cell now.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the Issue is, how the data is and where you get an error in the code ?

Comment: Got stuck? What error are you getting? Why are you using `Selection`? Why not specify a range, and then work with that object?

Comment: [Reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) may prove useful

Comment: Well I actually used a specified range, though I am looking for some quicker script.

Comment: @SamuelBalun please see my [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57148860/11167163)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reminder, What is `Rounddown`'s syntax? From the [Microsoft Excel documentation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/rounddown-function-2ec94c73-241f-4b01-8c6f-17e6d7968f53):

> `ROUNDDOWN(number, num_digits)`
>
> - **Number** – Required. Any real number that you want rounded down.
> - **Num_digits** – Required. The number of digits to which you want to round number.

So in  your code the first mistake I saw is here :

```
Selection.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown (Activecell.Value)
```

This line must be like below :

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown (Activecell.Value , 0)
```

So your code would be like that :

```
Sub Macro1()

  Dim Activecell As Range
  Dim rounddownvar As Double

    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

 For Each Activecell In Selection
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    rounddownvar = Application.WorksheetFunction.rounddown(Activecell.Value, 1)

    Debug.Print rounddownvar
 Next Activecell

End Sub
```

I added `Application.WorksheetFunction.rounddown(Activecell.Value, 1)` into a var because this line returns a number ...

Without select to be more efficient :

```
Sub AvoidingSelect()
Dim rng As Range, cll As Range
Set rng = Range(Range("A2:B2"), Range("A2:B2").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AA100000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

For Each cll In rng

If IsNumeric(cll.Value) Then
 Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(cll.Value, 0)
End If

Next
End Sub
```

**CAUTION:**

Please **respect** `RoundDown` syntax :

**RoundDown(cll.Value, 0)**  here **0** is the number of digit you want to delete after the **,** .

For Example :

**RoundDown(cll.Value, 0)** give : 0.000

**RoundDown(cll.Value, 3)** give : 0

Working :

```
Sub AvoidingSelect()
Dim rng As Range, cll As Range
Set rng = Range(Range("G2:G12854"), Range("G2:G12854").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G2:G12854").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G2:G12854").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

For Each cll In rng

If IsNumeric(cll.Value) Then
Debug.Print cll.Value
 cll = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(cll.Value, 8)
End If

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The code is not working because of the:  _Run-Time error '1004': This action won't work on multiple selections._

Comment: @SamuelBalun So you got multiple selection thats it ?

Comment: @SamuelBalun please look at my Edit, you will have to fit `range` where your values are I fixed em as `A2:B2` . 
Waiting for your feedbacks ;)

Comment: @SamuelBalun Try to copy and paste the last code avoiding select. Please **respect** `RoundDown` syntax : **RoundDown(cll.Value, 0)**  here **0** is the number of digit you want to delete after the **,** .
**For Example :**
**RoundDown(cll.Value, 0)** give : 0.000
**RoundDown(cll.Value, 3)** give : 0

Comment: I had to rework the code a bit as I got the _Error1004: pastespecial method of worksheet class failed_ I just specified the range for _PasteSpecial xlPasteValues_ see the code: `Sub AvoidingSelect()

Dim rng As Range, cll As Range
Set rng = Range("G2:G12854")

Sheets("Data").Range("G2:G12854").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Sheets("Data").Range("G2:G12854").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

For Each cll In rng

If IsNumeric(cll.Value) Then
 Range("G2:G12854") = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(cll.Value, 8)
End If

Next
End Sub`

Comment: @SamuelBalun See my last edit, I tested it its working you just got to copy and paste ;)

Comment: @SamuelBalun Waiting for your feedbacks ;)

Comment: Hi Dorian, thank you for your help. I managed to finish my code thanks to you! `Sub AvoidingSelect()

Dim rng As Range, cll As Range
Set rng = Range("G2:G12854")

Sheets("Data").Range("G2:G12854").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Sheets("Data").Range("G2:G12854").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

For Each cll In rng

If IsNumeric(cll.Value) Then
cll = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(cll.Value, 8)
End If

Next
End Sub
`

Comment: @SamuelBalun Glad that I could help you, may I ask you to accept answer ?